# IOS: verify an empty NSHomeDirectory

Tags: ios, xcode, home-directory

can I verify if inside my folder "Documents" in NSHomeDirectory are there or not at least 1 file?

```
NSError *error;
NSFileManager *fileMgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

// Point to Document directory
NSString *documentsDirectory = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"];

// Write out the contents of home directory to console
NSLog(@"Documents directory: %@", [fileMgr contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentsDirectory error:&error]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure!

NSFileManager's [`contentsOfDirectoryAtPath: error:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSFileManager/contentsOfDirectoryAtPath%3aerror%3a) method returns an array.

If it's an array with a count of zero, it's an empty directory.

If it returns an error, then the directory doesn't exist (or you passed in the path wrong).